# php socket programming - why exit on socket_accept($sock) === false

Tags: php, sockets

I'm reading [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php#example-5103) on simple server side socket programming. I can't understand this logic:

```
if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
    echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
    break;
}
```

from here:

```
do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

Why are breaking from the loop? Aren't we supposed to wait for a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `accept` may fail for a number of reasons, for example if it is interrupted by a signal or if the socket is not in listening state. Depending on the error you may want to do different things, but the simplest is to stop trying to accept connections and exit the program.

Comment: yeah, thanks, but what if the connection hasn't yet been initialized by a client? What does `socket_accept` return in that case?

Comment: You don't have to worry about that, `accept` waits until the connection is fully established.

Comment: Thanks, so socket_aacept doesnt return immediately, but waits until an attempt to connect is made, and rerurns true if succeful, false otherwise?

Comment: Almost. Accept returns a resource that identifies the connection with client when successful, and FALSE on error.